# Way to use command-line arguments with "Python: Run Python file in Terminal" in VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, command-line-arguments

Command line arguments in VSCode work fine when setup in the `launch.json` file.

But when using "Python: Run Python file in Terminal" *(run, not debug)*, the arguments in `launch.json` don't seem to appear in `sys.argv`.

Is there a way to pass command line arguments to Python code when using "Python: Run Python file in Terminal"?

Answer (score 1):

Vscode is just an editing shell, which is essentially a CMD command window. If you only use **run in terminal**, it will only run the file in the terminal without getting command line parameters.

You have the following alternative solutions:

1. Run with debug and define **args** in the `launch.json` file.
2. use method `parser.add_argument()` to pass arguments in your codes. For example:

   `import argparse`

   `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="para transfer")`

   `parser.add_argument("--para", type=str, default="helloWorld", help="para -> str type.")`

   `args = parser.parse_args()`

   `print(args)`
3. Manually run Python file in terminal and pass parameters.

   `python test.py  --para helloworld`
4. Try extension [code-runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner), you can set the custom command to run in the `settings.json`:

`{`

```
   "code-runner.customCommand": "echo Hello"
```

`}`

Answer (score -1):

You can pass arguments via `args` inside of the JSON.

Sample:

```json
{
     "version": "0.2.0",
     "configurations": [
         {
             "name": "Python: app.py",
             "type": "python",
             "request": "launch",
             "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.py",
             "args" : ["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]
         }
     ]
 }
```

Source: [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_set-configuration-options)

Comment: That only works for debug, not for run. (It was the first thing I tried.)